# Flutter Row Layout (the heighest child wins)

Tags: flutter, layout

I want to layout a row in flutter with dynamic height items inside the row.

example:

there  2 widgets inside the row (A and B).

Widget A is a small content filled Widget (height 100px).
The height of B is bigger (eg.. 500px.)

the row should now have the height of the biggest child (B).

How can i say that child A autosize to 500px?

I know ... i can wrap the row into a SizedBox with 500px an set the crossAxisAlignment of the row to stretch... but that is not what I want ...

Is there a way to auto size all childs inside of a row to the heightest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) widget like so with row's `crossAxisAlignment` set to `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`.

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      WidgetA(),
      WidgetB(),
    ],
  ),
)
```